# Simulate the href click in Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, dom-events, href

I have below code in my legacy project in jsp:

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Customer</th>
    <td colspan="2">
      <a href="myAction.do" target="view">CustomerLink</a></td>
</tr>
```

I want little modification in behaviour when we click CustomerLink. I just want to do some processing in Javascript function before hitting the action. **I am not getting how to simulate the href link behaviour in Javascript function?**

What I tried:-

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Customer</th>
    <td colspan="2">
      <a href="javascript:customerLinkClicked('myAction.do')" target="view">CustomerLink</a></td>
</tr>
```

// Javascript function

```
function customerLinkClicked(path)
{

    // simulate the href link behaviour, not sure how to do this


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:customerLinkClicked('myAction.do')" target="view">CustomerLink</a>
<script>
    function customerLinkClicked(path) {
        if (confirm('message'))
            document.location.href = path;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm) for getting confirmation dialog, which returns true or false, depending on choice. After that, default behaviour may be cancelled by [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) method.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Klaster_1/nXtvF/

```
$("a").on("click", function(event) {
    if(!window.confirm("Proceed?")){
        event.preventDefault()
    };
});
```

I've used jQuery in it, but it's totally optional.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
<a href="myAction.do" onclick="customerLinkClicked()" target="view">CustomerLink</a>
```

At first the onclick event handler will be processed, then the location will be changed to myAction.do.

If you want to prevent changing the location, you can write

```
onclick="return customerLinkClicked();"
```

Depending on the return value (true, false), the location change will happen. Or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.just copy and paste

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
if(confirm("Do you really want to go?"))
{window.open("yoursitename.do");}
}
</script
<a href="javascript:fnc()">click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid inline js, but for you current scenario.

```
    function customerLinkClicked(event) {
        if(!confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
              if(event.preventDefault) {
                  event.preventDefault();
              }
              else {
                   event.returnValue = false;
              } 
        } 
    }
```

HTML

```
<a href="myAction.do" onclick="customerLinkClicked(event);" target="view">CustomerLink</a>
```