# How to trigger search button on enter click?

Tags: javascript, php, search

I have made a search function with text field and button on my website. I've been trying to activate search on enter press but it doesn't work. I've tried many different methods, but none of them seems to be working. I've read there might be problems with this button not being "default". I am kind of new at this so any help is much appreciated!
This is script for search button, return button and search field:

```
        <div class="w3-top">

        <div title="Clear"><a id="returnbtn" class="aa bb cc">
          <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>
        </a></div>

        <div title="Search"><a id="searchbtn" class="aa bb cc">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </a>

        <a class="aa bb cc">
                        <?php
                        $searchstr='';
                        $sql = "SELECT ID, ISBN, Author, Title, Publisher, ReleaseYear, Barcode FROM Books ";
                        $searchstr='';
                        if (isset($_GET['searchstr'])){
                            $searchstr=strtolower($_GET['searchstr']);  
                        }
                        if($searchstr != ""){
                            $sql.="WHERE LOWER(Author) LIKE '%".$searchstr."%' OR LOWER(Title) LIKE '%".$searchstr."%' OR LOWER(Publisher) LIKE '%".$searchstr."%'";  
                        }
                        echo "<form id='search'>";
                        echo "<input id='searchfield'/ value='".$searchstr."' autocomplete='off'>";
                        echo "</form>";
                        ?>
        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And this is seach button function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#searchbtn").on('click', function(){
        var newLink = UpdateCurrentLink('searchstr', $("#searchfield").val(), null);
        newLink = UpdateCurrentLink('page', 1, newLink);
        window.location = newLink;
}); 
 $("#searchfield").keypress(function(e){
     if(e.which === 13){//Enter key pressed
        $('#searchbtn').click();//Trigger search button click event
    }
 });
```

Comment: Use AJAX to make it dynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate the href click in javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852549/simulate-the-href-click-in-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch every body keypress and check whether the pressed key is **Enter**: 
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").keypress(function(e){
        if (e.which === 13){
            alert('Keypress');
            $('#searchbtn').click();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It gives alert, but everytime I press it with text in search field nothing happens. If im, say, at the 3rd page of results, after pressing enter it returns me to the first site, while clicking search btn works perfectly fine.

Comment: It seems to be working, since link changes same way it does on click, however now Im unable to type anything in searchfield.

Comment: Placed e.preventDefault and return false before } and it seems to be working now. Thank you!

Comment: I did. It says upvotes by users with reputation lower than 15 are recorded, but do not change publicly displayed upvote score.

Answer (score 0):

$("searchbtn").click() function will not trigger click event. You have to use trigger method. You can try like this-

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#searchField").on('keypress', function(e){
      var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
      if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
          //console.log('enter press');
          $("#searchBtn").trigger('click')
      }
   })

    $("#searchBtn").on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log("on submit clicked");
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  
<body>
<form> 
  <input id="searchField" value=""/>
</form>
<p> <a href="#" id="searchBtn"> Search </a> </p> 
</body>
</html>
```